# Binary Neural Network using only bit and integer operations

Tags: neural-networks

Are there neural networks that do not make use of floating point arithmetic, i.e. ones that only use binary or (small) integer values throughout their whole classification computation?

I have found the following paper [Binarized Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02830.pdf), in which all weights seem to be binary values. However, as far as I understand, during a classification it does seem to use floating point arithmetic (see Algorithm 5), where it executes a method called BatchNorm (it is a little unclear what exactly BatchNorm is or why I need it). 
Is my understanding here correct or does this construction indeed perform only bit operations (or operations on small integers)?

Answer (score 1):

I skimmed through the article and immediately saw this:

> BNNs drastically reduce memory size and accesses, and replace **most** arithmetic operations with bit-wise operations, which is expected to substantially improve power-efficiency

So there are still some floating point arithmetic. But as an answer to your question: I don't *think* the network you want exists (yet), let me explain why:

Imagine a neuron that has 3 input connections. Each of these connections has a binary weight and a binary activation value. So you know that the value received from each of these connections is also binary.

The neuron computes its own activation by running an activation function over the **sum** of the received values + a bias. So even though the value from each connection is binary, the sum of them won't be (`1 + 1 + 1 = 3`).

Of course there would be ways around this, but I can't think of any.